# Adding form:checbox inside forEach

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a table in a jsp and i add the value to it as follows

```
<c:forEach items="${features}" var="feature">
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${feature.present == true}">
        <c:set var="featurePresent" value="REMOVE"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="featurePresent" value="ADD"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<tr>
    <td>${feature.name}</td>
    <td>${featurePresent}</td>
    <td><form:checkbox path="" value=""/></td>
</tr>   
</c:forEach>
```

I am trying to add the checkbox ..

My Feature class is

```
class Feature{
  private String name;
  private boolen present;
  private boolean checkbox
```

}

How can i set the checkbox in the jsp page

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your command object has a `List<Feature> features` property and you want the checkbox state for each Feature object in the list when you submit the form. You may try:

```
<c:forEach items="${features}" var="feature" varStatus="i">
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${feature.present == true}">
        <c:set var="featurePresent" value="REMOVE"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="featurePresent" value="ADD"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<tr>
    <td>${feature.name}</td>
    <td>${featurePresent}</td>
    <td><form:checkbox path="features[${i.index}].checkbox" value=""/></td>
</tr>   
</c:forEach>
```